# Unable to test a literal '+' in request parameter with TestRestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, junit

In a micro-service, based on Spring Boot 2.0.1, I have a `GET` Rest controller that takes a fromDate & toDate encoded as ISO strings (Shortened):

```
@GetMapping(value = "/range")
public ResponseEntity<MyDTO> getDateRange(
        @RequestParam
        @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
                ZonedDateTime fromDate,
        @RequestParam
        @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
                ZonedDateTime toDate) {

    if (fromDate.isAfter(toDate) || fromDate.isEqual(toDate)) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

So the requests should look something like (Fully URLEncoded):

`http://localhost:8080/range/?fromDate=2015-05-31T03%3A00%3A00.000%2B04%3A00&toDate=2015-05-31T03%3A30%3A00.000%2B04%3A00`

Or with just the `+` escaped:

`http://localhost:8080/range/?fromDate=2015-05-31T03:00:00.000%2B04:00&toDate=2015-05-31T03:30:00.000%2B04:00`

For reference, the un-URI-encoded string is:

`http://localhost:8080/range/?fromDate=2015-05-31T03:00:00.000+04:00&toDate=2015-05-31T03:30:00.000+04:00` - which doesn't work.

This rest controller works just fine when I execute `GETs` via Postman, or via tests using `MockMvc` in Spring Boot. But for completeness and my own understanding, I'd like to also test via `TestRestTemplate`. However, something about the use of `+` in the parameters is problematic. But I cannot figure why.

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class IntegrationTests {

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    public void test_get_in_range() throws Exception {
//        String uri = "/range?fromDate={fromDate}&toDate={toDate}";
//
//        Map<String, String> uriParams = new HashMap<>();
//        uriParams.put("fromDate", "2015-05-31T03:00:00.000+04:00");
//        uriParams.put("toDate", "2015-05-31T19:00:00.000+04:00");

        UriComponents uriComponents = UriComponentsBuilder
            .fromPath("/range")
            .queryParam("fromDate", "2015-05-31T03:00:00.000+04:00")
            .queryParam("toDate", "2015-05-31T19:00:00.000+04:00").build();
// Also tried with manually replacing + with %2B
// Also tried manually encoding the string

        ResponseEntity<String> getResponseEntity = restTemplate.withBasicAuth("cameraUser", "change_me")
                .getForEntity(uriComponents.toUriString(), String.class);
    }
}
```

The result from the server is `Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.time.ZonedDateTime] for value '2015-05-31T03:00:00.000 04:00'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [2015-05-31T03:00:00.000 04:00]`

It seems that the `+` in the string is replaced by a space, which also happens when I execute the un-encoded `GET` request from Postman.

Replacing the `+` with `%2B` in the test produces:

`Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.time.ZonedDateTime] for value '2015-05-31T03:00:00.000%2B04:00'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [2015-05-31T03:00:00.000%2B04:00]`

Does anyone know why? I suspect it is somehow related to auto-configuration and not using the same filters/converters (unclear about terminology) in test-mode as in default execution. I register no extra converters and rely 100% on Spring Boot auto-configuration.

Edit: I have created a sample application showing the issue [here](https://github.com/dajoni/test-rest-template-demo/).

Answer (score 0):

Encoding can be tricky, as some characters can be legal in different parts of the URI. Here, the "+" character is legal in a query parameter and it's not obvious from a Framework perspective what the client expects.

There is a dedicated section about [URI encoding in the Spring Framework](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webmvc/mvc-uri-building.html#uri-encoding) documentation that explains it all. Applying the advice to your test makes the test pass:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class UriexpandApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    void test_get_in_range() {
        URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder
                .fromPath("/range")
                .queryParam("fromDate", "{fromDate}")
                .queryParam("toDate", "{toDate}")
                .build("2015-05-31T03:00:00.000+04:00", "2015-05-31T19:00:00.000+04:00");

        ResponseEntity<String> getResponseEntity = restTemplate
                .getForEntity(uri, String.class);
        assertThat(getResponseEntity.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```